# Variant in 2:198

Tags: quran-recitation, naskh

Can someone shed some light on the variant below :

> Ukaz, Majanna and Dhul-Majaz were marketplaces in the Pre-Islamic period of ignorance. When Islam came, Muslims felt that marketing there might be a sin. So, the Divine Inspiration came: "There is no harm for you to seek the bounty of your Lord (in the seasons of Hajj)." (2.198) **Ibn `Abbas recited the Verse in this way**. (Sahih al-Bukhari 2050 Book 34, Hadith 4)

Can this mode of recitation be considered abrogated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an irregular (شاذة) qira'a. It is to be interpreted as an explanatory addition (tafsir) by a sahabi, not part of the Quran itself.

**Reference:**

> وقراءة بن عباس في مواسم الحج معدودة من الشاذ الذي صح إسناده وهو حجة وليس بقرآن
>
> فهي على هذا من القراءة الشاذة وحكمها عند الأئمة حكم التفسير
>
> <sup>— Fath al-Bari [4\290](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/2567) , [3\595](https://shamela.ws/book/1673/2250)</sup>